# Handling HTTPS certificate error with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, https, nsurlsession

I have the following code:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(data != nil){
            //...
        } else if(error != nil) {
            //...
        }

        //...
    })

    task.resume()
```

I´m trying to implement HTTPS request to the server with unauthorised CA and handle the unauthorised CA error properly. The problem is that it´s certificate, non-server, client error, so the response is nil. The only thing I have is the `Error` object, which has only two useful methods: `localisedDescription()` and `debugDescription()` .

As I suppose none of them should be really used for parsing error in the production, so what should  be the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 0):

guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
 let errorNetwork = error as! NSError ;
Print("Status:(String(describing: errorNetwork.code))"               completion(nil, .requestFailed, errorNetwork.code); // pass this to your layer above.
            return
          }

Comment: Please don't use `String(describing:)` to convert to String. Instead, just use string interpolation directly, or the normal String initializer (*not* the `describing` one) with an unwrapped value.